Synthesis with Verilog Parameter AUDIO_DW = 32 Results in LINT-1 Warning
I'm working on a Verilog project and encountering a warning during synthesis. When I set the parameter AUDIO_DW = 32, I get a LINT-1 warning. However, changing the parameter to AUDIO_DW = 2 makes the warning disappear. I would prefer to keep the parameter as AUDIO_DW = 32.
Should I modify the SDC file or the RTL code to proceed with the synthesis without warnings? If the SDC file needs adjustments, what specific commands should be included to address this issue?
module i2s_tx #(
    parameter AUDIO_DW = 32
)(
    input i_tx_sclk,
    input [AUDIO_DW-1:0] i_tx_prescaler,
    
    output reg o_tx_lrclk = 0,
    output reg o_tx_sdata = 0,

    input [AUDIO_DW-1:0] i_tx_left_chan,
    input [AUDIO_DW-1:0] i_tx_right_chan
);

reg [AUDIO_DW-1:0] tx_bit_cnt = 1;
reg [AUDIO_DW-1:0] tx_left = 0;
reg [AUDIO_DW-1:0] tx_right = 0;


always @(negedge i_tx_sclk) begin
    if (tx_bit_cnt >= i_tx_prescaler) begin
        tx_bit_cnt <= 1;
    end else begin
        tx_bit_cnt <= tx_bit_cnt + 1;
    end

    if (tx_bit_cnt == i_tx_prescaler && o_tx_lrclk) begin
        tx_left <= i_tx_left_chan;
        tx_right <= i_tx_right_chan;
    end
                
    o_tx_lrclk <= (tx_bit_cnt == i_tx_prescaler) ? ~o_tx_lrclk : o_tx_lrclk;
    
    o_tx_sdata <= o_tx_lrclk ? tx_right[AUDIO_DW - tx_bit_cnt] : tx_left[AUDIO_DW - tx_bit_cnt];
    
end

endmodule


Warning: In design 'i2s_tx_AUDIO_DW3', cell 'B_9' does not drive any nets. (LINT-1)
Warning: In design 'i2s_tx_AUDIO_DW3', cell 'B_10' does not drive any nets. (LINT-1)
Warning: In design 'i2s_tx_AUDIO_DW3', cell 'C105' does not drive any nets. (LINT-1)


There is a problem in the Verilog RTL code.
You declared tx_right and tx_bit_cnt as 32-bit signals.
The expression:
AUDIO_DW - tx_bit_cnt

evaluates to:
32 - tx_bit_cnt

There is no problem when the tx_bit_cnt module input takes on values from 0 to 32.  In that case, tx_right[32] to tx_right[0] are evaluated.
The problem comes when tx_bit_cnt takes on values greater than 32.  If tx_bit_cnt is 33, then tx_right[-1] is undefined.  You need to change your RTL code.  Think more carefully about what logic you are trying to design.
For example, if you are only interested in the range 0-31, that only requires 5 bits, and you can use reg [4:0] tx_bit_cnt.

Can I change reg [AUDIO_DW-1:0] tx_bit_cnt to reg [4:0] tx_bit_cnt?

@강영완: Yes, if that is what the specification of your design allows.  Give it a try.
